# Limitations and alternatives to Riemann Integral

Tags: integration

Why are there integrals different from Riemann's? That is, what aspect of a function makes it non-Riemann integrable but integrable by other approaches, what are the  other approaches, and are their results differentiable or do they not have inverse operations?

Comment: Look up any introduction to Measure theory, it always discusses limitations of Riemann integrals and why people should yuse Lebesgue integrals instead

Comment: Another alternate is the *gauge integral* or *Henstock-Kurzweil integral* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henstock–Kurzweil_integral

Answer (score 2):

There is an amazing book out there that directly covers most of your question: Cauchy, Riemann, Riemann-Stieltjes, Lebesgue, Lebesgue-Stieltjes, Henstock-Kurzweil, Wiener and Feynman.

**[A Garden of Integrals](http://www.maa.org/press/ebooks/a-garden-of-integrals)** by Frank Burk (published by Mathematical Association of America)

Hope it helps.